# How to identify this element in protractor?

Tags: javascript, testing, selenium, protractor, end-to-end

When I view some customer information, I see the customer information displayed at the bottom. I believe it comes from JSON call.

How to identify this element? I tried className but not working. Thanks for your help. And tried this css as well. `.override-info hide-mobile ng-scope`. I need to assert the name matches to `John Grish`:

```
<div class="override-info hide-mobile ng-scope" ng-if="overrideCustInfo">
    <p class="override-info-title">You are viewing</p>
    <p class="override-info-dtl ng-binding">John Grish</p>
    <p class="override-info-dtl ng-binding">1177 Montogomery st</p>
    <p class="override-info-dtl ng-binding">San Francisco, CA</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can rely on class names:

```
expect(element
    .all(by.css("div.override-info p.override-info-dtl"))
    .first().getText()
).toEqual("John Grish");
```

Comment: Thank you. It worked. I am not sure what first() does here? I am new to protractor and working on it on and off.

Comment: @user2744620 `element.all()` in conjunction with `first()` helps to locate the first occurrence of `p` with `override-info-dtl` class.

Comment: I'd like to add that those appear to use bindings so you have access to the source files and can find out what the binding is for each of those entries can use something like the following;

element(by.binding('{{first.name}}')).getText();

Comment: @Sirk adding to the addition. Note that `by.binding('{{first.name}}')` syntax [is deprecated](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/8b77fd836b039965722e01e83c0e71b36bf881f6/lib/locators.js#L103), use `by.binding('first.name')` instead.

Comment: @alecxe oh wow i didn't realise, I don't use binding often and am also quite an old version of protractor so thanks for that.